# I am trying make sms service at aws server using Laravel 5.8 but getting error below

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

This is my controller file

```
<?php
{
protected function sendSMS(){
    //echo "test";die;
    $sms = AWS::createClient('sns');

 $result = $sms->publish([
            'Message' => 'Hello, This is just a test Message',
            'PhoneNumber' => '+919711......',    
            'MessageAttributes' => [
                'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType'  => [
                    'DataType'    => 'String',
                    'StringValue' => 'Transactional',
                 ]
             ],
          ]);
 var_dump($result);
 return Response()->json($result);
}
```

Above code getting error:

> {
>       "message": "Error executing \"Publish\" on \"https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:\nhttp://sns.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-03-31/\">\n  \n    Sender\n    `InvalidClie (truncated...)\n InvalidClientTokenId (client): The security token included in the request is invalid. - http://sns.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-03-31/\">\n  \n    Sender\n    InvalidClientTokenId`\n    The security token included in the request is invalid.\n  \n  a38862b7-7857-509e-aba6-3767d5bd7efb\n\n",
>       "exception": "Aws\Sns\Exception\SnsException",
>       "file": "/home/kanak/workspace/btutee-app/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/WrappedHttpHandler.php",

I have follow article  https://www.kerneldev.com/2018/01/03/send-sms-in-laravel-using-aws-sns/ 
i have search everywhere above this but not getting exact solution for this.i have fixed all keys right.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54242154/aws-sns-is-not-sending-sms-anymore